# Change WPF DataGrid cell Background color on CellEditEnding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `WPF` `DataGrid` and a `event handler` `CellEditEnding`, I want a simple `code` to change the background color of edited `cell` inside the `event handler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below makes a cell bold when successfully edited.

**Style**

```
  <Style TargetType="Controls:DataGridCell" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}}" 
   x:Key="CellBoldStyle">
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Duration="00:00:00.5"                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty
                                    ="(TextBlock.FontWeight)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Normal}" />
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Bold}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

**Column**

```
  <Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
             Binding="{Binding Side, Mode=TwoWay, 
                               NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
             CellStyle="{StaticResource CellBoldStyle}" />
```

Comment: I particularly want to change the background color of cell inside the event handler `CellEditEnding`

Comment: Any reason to do that? Above also instead of `TextBlock.FontWeight` you can use `BackGround` property. And instead of `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` use `ColorAnimation`.